# Video Splash en con Bootstrap 3 en version mobile

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-3, video

tengo un problema con un video en mp4 el cual deseo ponerlo como video splash antes que redirija al HTML home. En la version desktop se reproduce con normalidad pero en la version mobile no aparece el video.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#video').fadeOut(1000, function() {
          window.location.href = 'views/home.html';
        });
      }, 6000);
});
```

```css
#video {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="video">
    <video autoplay muted loop class="embed-responsive-item">
      <source src="assets/video/video-splashTrim.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
    <!--====== Javascripts & Jquery ======-->
   <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```